# How can I run some script code when an item is forwarded to an Exchange public folder?

Tags: email, scripting, outlook, exchange-server

I am working on a proof of concept for some workflow automation using Exchange 2007 public folders.

I am trying to write some code that can be run any time an item is forwarded into a particular public folder - these items arrive automatically via email and are automatically routed by Exchange into this public folder.

Primarily what I need to do is parse the Subject of an the arriving email item, perform some processing on it, and then set some fields on the item in the folder. These fields are then used for searching, displaying in views, and controlling the workflow associated with the item.

The MSDN documentation for automation of Exchange public folders doesn't seem do identify a way to do this.

Comment: Good point, it's Ex2007 - all add that to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by writing an Exchange 2007 transport agent.

http://www.msexchange.org/articles_tutorials/exchange-server-2007/planning-architecture/understanding-transport-agents-part1.html

Comment: This is what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

Event sinks are one way to go Check out
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204074.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/exchange/ManagedEventSinks.aspx

but I must say I have not done it in a public folder before .. 
The other way may be to use notifications on WebDav or EWS if you are using those versions.

Marcus

Comment: Event sinks were always a bad idea and I don't think they're even supported in Exchange 2007 anymore.  If they are, they definitely won't be supported in Exchange 2010.

Comment: You can use them in 2007, but you are right they have gone in 2010.